# getopts in C, command line arguments

Tags: c, command-line-arguments, getopts

What does in getopts the "abc:d:" mean? How does this work?

example:

```
while ((option = getopt(argc, argv,"abc:d::")) != -1)
```

I am writing a program in C and it has to use command line arguments like:

```
compress -t [1..5] -[c,d]
```

I can't get it right.

Comment: https://linux.die.net/man/3/getopt describes the `optstring` very well. The `:` afterwards says the option requires an argument. You should probably use `"cdt:"`

Comment: thank you! Ok, I will have to use "t:cd". Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

[linux.die.net/man/3/getopt](https://linux.die.net/man/3/getopt) describes the `optstring` very well. The `:` afterwards says the option requires an argument. You should probably use `"cdt:"`
                    – mch